# Make music list using Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a music player using Java Swing. In the program that I want to make, there is a playlist that I have already chosen. I want to show that music in a gui by listing. I want to choose that gui list and play the music. I think that I can make the list by using `for` or `while`, but I dont have any ideas.
How to make music lists on GUI?

Comment: You could use components like `JList` or `JTextArea` to display them using text/icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) (dropdown menu).

Example (from link):

```
String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };

//Create the combo box, select item at index 4.
//Indices start at 0, so 4 specifies the pig.
JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
petList.setSelectedIndex(4);
petList.addActionListener(this);
```

You could also use JButtons, along with a layout manager.